# How to find a chain of generalized eigenvectors of matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\textbf{A}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
-60 & 0 & 26 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ be, find a chain of generalized eigenvectors.

Eigenvalues : $\lambda_{1}=0 ;\quad \lambda_{2}=0 ;\quad \lambda_{3}=2 ;\quad \lambda_{4}=0$.

For $\lambda_{1}=0$, $v_{1}= \left(\begin{array}{c}
v_{11} \\
v_{12} \\
v_{13} \\
v_{14}
\end{array}\right)$

$$(\textbf{A}-\lambda_{1} \textbf{I})v_{1}=0 ; \quad \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
-\lambda_{1} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\lambda_{1} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2-\lambda_{1} & 0\\
-60 & 0 & 26 & -\lambda_{1}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
v_{11} \\
v_{12} \\
v_{13} \\
v_{14}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right)$$

$$ \left \{ \begin{array}{c}
-\lambda_{1}v_{11}=0 \\
-\lambda_{1}v_{12}=0 \\
(2-\lambda_{1})v_{13}=0 \\
-60v_{11}+26v_{13}-\lambda_{1}v_{14}=0
\end{array}\right.;\quad v_{11}=v_{13}=0;\quad v_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
v_{12} \\
0 \\
v_{14}
\end{array}\right)$$

For $\lambda_{2}=0$, $v_{2}= \left(\begin{array}{c}
v_{21} \\
v_{22} \\
v_{23} \\
v_{24}
\end{array}\right)$

$$(\textbf{A}-\lambda_{2} \textbf{I})v_{2}=v_{1} ; \quad \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
-\lambda_{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\lambda_{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2-\lambda_{2} & 0\\
-60 & 0 & 26 & -\lambda_{2}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
v_{21} \\
v_{22} \\
v_{23} \\
v_{24}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
v_{12} \\
0 \\
v_{14}
\end{array}\right)$$

$$ \left \{ \begin{array}{c}
-\lambda_{2}v_{21}=0 \\
-\lambda_{2}v_{22}=v_{12} \\
(2-\lambda_{2})v_{23}=0 \\
-60v_{21}+26v_{23}-\lambda_{2}v_{24}=v_{14}
\end{array}\right.;\quad v_{23}=v_{12}=0;\quad v_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
v_{14}
\end{array}\right);\quad  v_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
-\dfrac{v_{14}}{60} \\
v_{22} \\
0 \\
v_{24}
\end{array}\right)$$

For $\lambda_{3}=2$, $v_{3}= \left(\begin{array}{c}
v_{31} \\
v_{32} \\
v_{33} \\
v_{34}
\end{array}\right)$

$$(\textbf{A}-\lambda_{3} \textbf{I})v_{3}=0 ; \quad \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
-\lambda_{3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\lambda_{3} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2-\lambda_{3} & 0\\
-60 & 0 & 26 & -\lambda_{3}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
v_{31} \\
v_{32} \\
v_{33} \\
v_{34}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right)$$

$$ \left \{ \begin{array}{c}
-\lambda_{3}v_{31}=0 \\
-\lambda_{3}v_{32}=0 \\
(2-\lambda_{3})v_{33}=0 \\
-60v_{31}+26v_{33}-\lambda_{3}v_{34}=0
\end{array}\right.;\quad v_{31}=v_{32}=0; v_{34}=13v_{33}\quad v_{3}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
v_{33} \\
13v_{33}
\end{array}\right)$$

how can I find the last generalized eigenvector?

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues are $0$ and $2$.

Calculating $\ker A$, we get:

$$Ax = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
-60 & 0 & 26 & 0}\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4} = 0 \implies \left \{ \begin{array}{c}
2x_3=0 \\
-60x_1+26x_3 =0 \\
\end{array}\right. \implies x_1 = x_3 = 0$$

so $\ker A = \operatorname{span}\{e_2, e_4\}$. We have $\dim\ker A = 2$, which is less than the algebraic multiplicity of $0$. Therefore, we continue onto $\ker A^2$:

$$A^2x = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 52 & 0}\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4} = 0 \implies 52x_3 = 0 \implies x_3 = 0$$

so $\ker A^2 = \operatorname{span}\{e_1, e_2, e_4\}$. Now $\dim\ker A^2 = 3$ is equal to the algebraic multiplicity of $0$, so there are no more generalized eigenvectors for $0$.

For the eigenvalue $2$, we have

$$(A - 2I)x = \pmatrix{-2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-60 & 0 & 26 & -2}\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4} = \left \{ \begin{array}{c}
-2x_1 = 0\\
-2x_2 = 0\\
-60x_1+26x_3 -2x_4 =0 \\
\end{array}\right. \implies \left \{ \begin{array}{c}
x_1 = x_2 = 0 \\
x_4 = 13x_3 \\
\end{array}\right. $$

so $\ker (A - 2I) = \operatorname{span}\{e_3 + 13e_4\}$.

Therefore, one set of generalized eigenvectors is given by

$$\left\{\pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0},\pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0},\pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1},\pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 13}\right\}$$